# Mockito: call a stub method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm very familiar with mocking in scripting languages.  In most languages I've used, there is a mocking framework that allows you to call a fake function.  For example, in JavaScript, you would use [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/stubs/) and call `callsFake`, then pass in a function:

```
var sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
sandbox.stub(myObject, 'some_method').callsFake(() => {
    //do stuff
});
```

In Perl, you can use [`Test::MockModule->mock`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockModule):

```
my $mockedModule = Test::MockModule->new('Some::Module');
$mockedModule->mock('someMethod', sub {
    #Do stuff
});
```

Is it possible in Java to do this?  The best I've been able to do in Java is use [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) to return a fixed value, by calling `when(mock(MyClass.class).method()).thenReturn("foo");`.  But this always returns `"foo"`, and does nothing else, when `MyClass.method()` is called.  I want to know if it's possible instead to tell Mockito to call a fake method instead of calling the real one.

Is this possible in Mockito, or in some other mocking framework for Java.

Comment: Maybe just creating a class which extends the class that you want to mock could work?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question here. You're not testing the mocks, you're testing the class that uses the mocks to do something of value. You don't want your class under test to call realClass.method(), but rather mockedClass.method(). Ultimately, you want to know that the proper methods on each of the mocks are called and return the expected results, but this is in service of testing the class under test.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock I added some clarification using examples form other languages

Answer (score 1):

One option is create a class which extends the class and overrides the behaviour that you want don't execute on tests.

The other option is this:

```
when(mockedClass.method()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    private int count = 0;
    List<String> values = asList("a", "b")
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return values.get(count++)
    }
});
```

But it could promote hard reading and extreme complexity in tests.

Comment: The thenX methods may not work the way you think. They all run the code in the real method then return or answer with whatever you mock with the when. You have to use the doX methods to completely override the real method but it's not recommended since doX methods have no type checking, in general use the doX mocking sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`AdditionalAnswers#answer(...)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.20.0/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#answer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer1-), e.g.:

```
doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.answer((a, b) -> a.equals(b))))
    .when(mock).execute(anyString(), anyString());
```

There is also [`delegatesTo`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.20.0/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#delegatesTo-java.lang.Object-), which might be of some use.